# What is Brad Pitt wearing in this scene?

Tags: props, babylon

[image]

In this movie, ***Babylon*** (2022), Brad Pitt is wearing a pair of black metal strappings above his socks, what are they?

Comment: Voting to leave open as per [Which trivia questions are on-topic and which are off-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are sock suspenders (or [**sock garters**](https://blog.suspenderstore.com/an-introduction-to-sock-garters-wearing-suspenders-for-socks/#:%7E:text=In%20case%20you%27ve%20never,from%20slipping%20down%20your%20leg.)).

The operate like normal suspenders (or braces) and hold your socks up.

> The garter's sole purpose is to prevent socks from slipping down your leg. Some people refer to them as a sock strap, while others call them sock suspenders.

[image]

Comment: @YuZhang Yes. Specifically, elastic really wasn't a thing, so the opening of the sock was nowhere near as stretchy as they are today. You couldn't rely on it "hugging" your leg to keep it in place. Instead, the sock garters used the flare of your calf to prevent things from sliding downward.